# What does $(var) mean in Actionscript?

Tags: actionscript, operators

I see $(var) often in the Actionscript code I am looking through, where var is a variable that is previously defined. What does it mean exactly?

Comment: Do you mean literally "$(var)" with the parentheses, or a variable named something like "$input"?

Comment: with the parentheses. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT:
Thanks to joshtynjalas correction, the following line is wrong, sorry! The dollar sign can actually be used exactly the same way as in JS (see example at the bottom):

<del>In **Actionscript** you cannot use the **$** sign on its own as a property name (at least in AS2 and AS3).</del>

It is possible to use it in combination with other characters though. 
It happens that developers uses it as prefix to identify static fields or constants (e.g. `private static var $boxHeight:int = 480` ).

FYI, here's a word from the ECMA Script specifications :

> "This standard specifies one departure
>   from the grammar given in the Unicode
>   standard: The dollar sign ($) and the
>   underscore (_) are permitted anywhere
>   in an identifier. The dollar sign is
>   intended for use only in mechanically
>   generated code."

I guess you mixed it up with **Javascript** where the dollar sign can be considered as a variable name. Thanks to that you can assign it as a shortcut reference to a predefined function.

```
function popup(value)
{
   alert(value)
}

$ = popup;

$("hello");
$("world");
```

The practice was widely introduced by **Prototype(.js)** in order to abstract the quite painful `getElementById(id_name);`

Comment: The following code works fine in AS3 var $:String = "hi";trace($); You can also name functions with only the $ character, just like JavaScript. That's part of the ECMAScript spec, and Adobe's implementation does not differ in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

It's a function called $, [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works) actually uses it a lot